# Graphics drawn onto Full Screen using LWJGL not the correct size

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So I'm trying to learn to use LWJGL and I created this basic application which puts the application into full screen then draw some graphics which fill the screen. Heres the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class TextureExample {

/** The texture that will hold the image details */
private Texture texture, texture2;
private Texture charcter;
int positionX = 705, positionY = 790;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
int onScreenCount = 0;
String runningMode = "START_SCREEN";

String playerFacing = "RIGHT";
int jumpHeight = 0, playerHasJumped = 0;

/**
 * Start the example
 */
public void start() {
    initGL();
    init("res/openingLogo.png");

    while (true) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        render();

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            positionX -= 1;
            playerFacingSwap("LEFT");
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT)) {
                positionX -= 2;
            }
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            positionX += 1;
            playerFacingSwap("RIGHT");
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT)) {
                positionX += 2;
            }
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)
                || Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
            if (jumpHeight < 100) {
                jumpHeight += 5;
            }
        }

        if (playerHasJumped <= jumpHeight) {
            positionY -= 1;
            playerHasJumped += 1;
        } else if (playerHasJumped > jumpHeight) {
            jumpHeight = 0;
            positionY += 1;
            playerHasJumped -= 1;
        }

        onScreenCount += 1;
        if (onScreenCount == 240) {
            init("res/openingScreen.png");
        } else if (onScreenCount == 480) {
            runningMode = "MAIN_MENU";
            init("res/background.png");
        }

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);

        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Initialise the GL display
 * 
 * @param width
 *            The width of the display
 * @param height
 *            The height of the display
 */
private void initGL() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(100, 100));

        setDisplayMode(1440, 900, true);

        screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = Display.getHeight();

        System.out.println("Display Size Is: "
                + Integer.toString(screenWidth) + " x "
                + Integer.toString(screenHeight));

        Display.create();
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // enable alpha blending
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

/**
 * Initialise resources
 */
public void init(String resource) {

    try {
        // load texture from PNG file
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",
                ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource));
        texture2 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",
                ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/foreground.png"));
        charcter = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",
                ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/tempCharcter.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void playerFacingSwap(String currentMovement) {
    if (currentMovement == "RIGHT" && playerFacing == "LEFT") {
        try {
            charcter = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader
                    .getResourceAsStream("res/tempCharcter.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        playerFacing = "RIGHT";
    } else if (currentMovement == "LEFT" && playerFacing == "RIGHT") {
        try {
            charcter = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader
                    .getResourceAsStream("res/tempCharcterLeft.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        playerFacing = "LEFT";
    }
}

public void render() {
    if (runningMode == "START_SCREEN") {
        drawImage(texture, 0, 0, 2048, 1050);
    } else if (runningMode == "MAIN_MENU") {
        drawImage(texture, 0, 0, 2048, 990);
        drawImage(texture2, 0, 0, 2048, 990);

        drawImage(charcter, positionX, positionY, 60, 120);
    }
}

public void drawImage(Texture Image, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Color.white.bind();
    Image.bind(); // or GL11.glBind(texture.getTextureID());

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    GL11.glEnd();
}

/**
 * Main Class
 */
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    TextureExample textureExample = new TextureExample();
    textureExample.start();
}

/**
 * Set the display mode to be used
 * 
 * @param width
 *            The width of the display required
 * @param height
 *            The height of the display required
 * @param fullscreen
 *            True if we want fullscreen mode
 */
public void setDisplayMode(int width, int height, boolean fullscreen) {

    // return if requested DisplayMode is already set
    if ((Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth() == width)
            && (Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight() == height)
            && (Display.isFullscreen() == fullscreen)) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        DisplayMode targetDisplayMode = null;

        if (fullscreen) {
            DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
            int freq = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
                DisplayMode current = modes[i];

                if ((current.getWidth() == width)
                        && (current.getHeight() == height)) {
                    if ((targetDisplayMode == null)
                            || (current.getFrequency() >= freq)) {
                        if ((targetDisplayMode == null)
                                || (current.getBitsPerPixel() > targetDisplayMode
                                        .getBitsPerPixel())) {
                            targetDisplayMode = current;
                            freq = targetDisplayMode.getFrequency();
                        }
                    }

                    // if we've found a match for bpp and frequence against
                    // the
                    // original display mode then it's probably best to go
                    // for this one
                    // since it's most likely compatible with the monitor
                    if ((current.getBitsPerPixel() == Display
                            .getDesktopDisplayMode().getBitsPerPixel())
                            && (current.getFrequency() == Display
                                    .getDesktopDisplayMode().getFrequency())) {
                        targetDisplayMode = current;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            targetDisplayMode = new DisplayMode(width, height);
        }

        if (targetDisplayMode == null) {
            System.out.println("Failed to find value mode: " + width + "x"
                    + height + " fs=" + fullscreen);
            return;
        }

        Display.setDisplayMode(targetDisplayMode);
        Display.setFullscreen(fullscreen);

    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to setup mode " + width + "x" + height
                + " fullscreen=" + fullscreen + e);
    }
}
 }
```

The screen is measured when the application starts and it all sets to full screen fine, it returns the measurements of 1440x900 Pixels which is the size of my display. But if I try and draw my graphics (The image is 1440x900 pixels as well) it does not fill the whole screen, to get any images to fill the whole screen I have to draw them 2048x1050, I can't see any relevance in this number to my display so I was wondering if anyone knows why I have to do this and if there is a fix.

**EDIT** After a Lot of research I've found out that its common for Slick to scale Textures to the nearest power of 2 but I still don't get why this means that I have to draw the graphics to this size, surely I should still be drawing them at the size of the screen.

Comment: Does it happen as well if you hardcode fullscreen with correct size without going through your `setDisplayMode()` function? Example : http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_5_(Fullscreen)#Using_Fullscreen

Comment: Yes the same issue occurs, And the setDisplayMode() function was taken from that tutorial.

Comment: If you happen to use a mac with retina display, try changing display mode to scaled and try again. I remember having similar issue related to that.

Comment: Running on a Late 2011 macbook pro (non retina) so that shouldn't be an issue, but thanks any way.